How Do I turn off Fn Lock on my Acer Aspire 5?
Is there a Non-BIOS way to not have to press Fn + F12
if I want to Inspect a page!
I would naturally hit F1 for the help menu in a browser but instead it puts my laptop to sleep! I haven't found any solutions to this so far. Thanks in advance!

No, there isn't a "Non-BIOS way" (actually UEFI, the firmware that replaced BIOS a long time ago) to change it, because that is precisely a firmware (UEFI) setting.
Since some years ago it has become the standards for most vendors to enable the secondary functions instead of the traditional F-keys functions by default. The reason is frequency of use and users preference. The secondary functions/actions and particularly the "multimedia" ones are used a lot more than specific F1 - F12 actions is specific software, therefore the vast majority of users prefers to access them directly instead of with the "FN" combo.
You can change it back to the "traditional" setup at your firmware (UEFI) settings only.

Exactly what i needed!
